# Trim searchtext in jquery datatables using default searchbox

Tags: jquery, datatables

I would like the user to do free-text search across all the columns of the data table with server-side property marked as false.Before searching the table how can I trim the search text given by the user?.
I do not want the trim functionality on key-based events as the user would be searching for text with space in between as well.

Ex: 
1) 'Micro '       -> 'Micro'
2) 'Micro Soft  ' -> 'Micro Soft'

Comment: You want the search to be done on a button click?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

My HTML code

```
<input type='text' id = 'searchtext'/>
<input type='button' id = 'btnSearch' value= 'search data'></input>
```

Javascript side

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#btnSearch').click(function(){
     alert( $('#searchtext').val())
     var datatable = $('#example').DataTable();
     datatable.search( $('#searchtext').val() ).draw();
   });
    var datatable = $('#example').DataTable();

} );
```

On click of a button, we can get text being entered and trim it and then filter datatable.

[Codpen for this.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQxjmm)